# pcl in ros fuerte: missing headers?

Tags: pcl, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I install PCL 1.5.1 from source or by using the debian packages provided on pointclouds.org, the io directory is as follows:

/usr/include/pcl-1.5/pcl/io:

> file_io.h  impl  lzf.h     oni_grabber.h  openni_grabber.h  pcd_io.h            ply_io.h  vtk_lib_io.h
> grabber.h  io.h  obj_io.h  openni_camera  pcd_grabber.h     pcl_io_exception.h  vtk_io.h

However, the fuerte package is missing some of these headers, including openni_grabber.h.

/opt/ros/fuerte/include/pcl-1.5/pcl/io:

> file_io.h  impl  lzf.h     pcd_grabber.h  pcl_io_exception.h  vtk_io.h
> grabber.h  io.h  obj_io.h  pcd_io.h       ply_io.h            vtk_lib_io.h

I'm on ubuntu 11.10. What's the reason for the discrepancy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33376/pcl-in-ros-fuerte:-missing-headers?/) by [joschu](https://answers.ros.org/users/896/joschu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2012-05-06

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-05-06**:
Same thing happened to me, PCL 1.5.1 from source on OSX. I think there is an error in their Makefiles.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-08-09**:
Can you bring this up on ros-users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PCL from pointclouds.org has different openni_grabber framework and the openni_launch that ships with ROS is different. Both cannot exist and work simultaneously. Thus if you have pcl that ships with ROS, it works with openni_launch that can grab kinect data for you. I think its the same with the other headers/packages too.

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0